# How to run dynamodb local console?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

[I'm following the tic tac toe](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TicTacToe.Phase2.html) tutorial for dynamoDB and I don't see how to pull up a local console. I know that using localhost:8000/shell gives me a local shell, but I can't easily view or manipulate the contents of a database. The tutorial seems to show how to do this. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

There's no UI like most database IDEs give you, but if you go through the menus there is a list of snippets that the shell will generate for you. The snippets cover all the commands you need and when you run them the results will display in the output window. The output window also lets you replay a command by clicking a "refresh" button or it will re-copy the command you ran into the shell window so you can edit it before running it again.